# Debug and release modes invoke method in different way?

Tags: swift, xcode

I define a class called `Dog`:

```
class Dog {
    func run() { }
}
```

And invoke the method `run`:

```
let d = Dog()
d.run()
```

If in debug mode the method will invoke through `table`:

```
0x105cea02f <+127>: movq   (%rax), %rdx
0x105cea032 <+130>: movq   0x50(%rdx), %rdx
0x105cea036 <+134>: movq   %rax, %r13
0x105cea039 <+137>: movq   %rax, -0x50(%rbp)
0x105cea03d <+141>: callq  *%rdx
```

But in release mode the method will invoke directly:

```
0x10e26a7cf <+127>: movq   %rax, %r13
0x10e26a7d2 <+130>: movq   %rax, -0x50(%rbp)
0x10e26a7d6 <+134>: callq  0x10e26a4d0               ; SwiftDemo.Dog.run() -> () at ViewController.swift:12
```

Does compiler help us to optimize our code? And in which condition it will help us do it?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is an IDE, not a compiler. The Swift compiler does the optimisation.

However, Xcode passes the optimisation settings to the compiler, which by default differ for debug and release builds. By default, debug builds are not optimised (`-O0` flag passed to the compiler), while release builds are optimised (`-Os` flag).

You can find the relevant settings under your Xcode target's `Build Settings > Optimisation Level`.

Comment: @dowZhang you cannot really tell while writing the code which version the compiler will be able to optimise better. However, the compiler always _tries_ to optimise the generated code. Unless you are working on a really performance critical task, you should not worry about compiler optimisations.